# Какие есть библиотеки для быстрой работы со списками?

Tags: python

Есть ли в Python какие-либо библиотеки для того, чтобы быстрее проходится по спискам или работать с ними?

Comment: [numpy](https://numpy.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NumPy](https://yandex.ru/turbo/ru.wikipedia.org/s/wiki/NumPy) — библиотека с открытым исходным кодом для языка программирования Python. Возможности:

- поддержка многомерных массивов (включая матрицы);
- поддержка высокоуровневых математических функций, предназначенных для работы с многомерными массивами.

Математические алгоритмы, реализованные на интерпретируемых языках (например, Python), часто работают гораздо медленнее тех же алгоритмов, реализованных на компилируемых языках (например, Фортран, Си, Java). Библиотека NumPy предоставляет реализации вычислительных алгоритмов (в виде функций и операторов), оптимизированные для работы с многомерными массивами.

Answer (score 4):

Кроме уже указанной [в соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1188570) библиотеки NumPy, существует [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html), основанная на NumPy и предоставляющая [богатейший API](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/index.html) для чтения/записи, обработки и визуализации табличных данных.

Основной объект в Pandas - `DataFrame` - таблица с именованными столбцами. Каждый столбец имеет свой тип данных.

Фактически `DataFrame` является набором именованных NumPy векторов.

NumPy не очень хорошо справляется со смешанными типами данных.